# php algorithm last bloack of number

Tags: php

I search an algorithm for the result of a ldap code in php I have write

```
<?php

// LDAP server and port configuration
$ldapServer = "ldaps://ldap2.u-bordeaux.fr";
$ldapPort = 636;

// Admin credentials
$username = "cn=gpuc-operator,ou=admin,dc=u-bordeaux,dc=fr";
$password = "KvQjf*t%";

// Base DN for LDAP search
$baseDN = "dc=u-bordeaux,dc=fr";
$ouGroups = "ou=groups," . $baseDN;

// Establish LDAP connection
$ldapConnection = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);

// Check if connection was successful
if ($ldapConnection) {

    // Set LDAP options for version and referrals
    ldap_set_option($ldapConnection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldapConnection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    // Attempt to bind to the LDAP server with provided credentials
    $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ldapConnection, $username, $password);

    // Check if binding was successful
    if ($ldapBind) {

        // LDAP search filter to find groups based on criteria
        $searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=*adm*)(cn=*:tous)(!(cn=*local*)))";

        // Perform the LDAP search
        $result = ldap_search($ldapConnection, $ouGroups, $searchFilter, ["cn"]);

        // Get the entries from the search result
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $result);

        // Check if any groups were found
        if ($entries["count"] > 0) {

            // Loop through the entries and display the common names (CN)
            for ($i = 0; $i < $entries["count"]; $i++) {
                echo "CN : " . $entries[$i]["cn"][0] . "\n";
            }

        } else {
            // No matching groups found
            echo "No groups found.";
        }

    } else {
        // LDAP binding failed, check credentials or server configuration
        echo "LDAPS connection failed. Please check your credentials.";
    }

    // Close the LDAP connection
    ldap_close($ldapConnection);

} else {
    // Unable to connect to LDAPS server, check server configuration
    echo "Unable to connect to LDAPS server. Please check server configuration.";
}

?>
```

I have for result this

```
CN : ubx:adm:2098:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2103:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2103:2104:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2103:2105:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2106:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:2107:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:2108:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2101:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:2109:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:2110:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2113:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2118:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2121:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2123:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2124:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2125:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2126:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2126:2127:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2126:2128:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2129:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2130:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:2132:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:2133:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:2134:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2145:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2144:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:2143:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:2142:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:2141:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2139:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2138:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2137:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2136:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2124:2147:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2124:2146:tous
CN : ubx:adm:33:2150:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2004:2014:2162:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2114:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2115:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2116:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2117:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2119:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2120:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2164:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:tous
```

And I want this

```
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2103:2104:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2103:2105:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2106:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:2107:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:2108:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2101:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:2109:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:2110:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2113:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2118:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2121:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2123:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2124:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2125:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2126:2127:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2126:2128:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2129:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2130:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:2132:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:2133:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:2134:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2145:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2144:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:2143:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:2142:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:2141:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2139:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2138:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2137:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2135:2136:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2124:2147:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:2124:2146:tous
CN : ubx:adm:33:2150:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2004:2014:2162:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2114:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2115:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2116:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2117:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2119:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2120:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:2164:tous
```

I don't want to display duplicates on the last block of numbers
do you have any idea how to write this in php?
I can't find the good algorithm to do this

dplicates are

```
CN : ubx:adm:2098:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:2103:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2122:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2126:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2131:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2140:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:2163:tous
```

you can see this is the last block number who shouldn't be appear

Comment: What are the dupllicates?

Comment: duplicates are CN : ubx:adm:2098:tous 
CN : ubx:adm:2098:2099:tous  CN : ubx:adm:2098:2100:tous  CN : ubx:adm:2098:2102:tous CN : ubx:adm:2097:tous
CN : ubx:adm:2097:2112:tous etc etc

Comment: Sort your data in descending order. Then check each entry to see if it's a prefix of the previous entry and skip it.

Comment: If you have this as an array you could use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicates.